# When I transferred the program I made in eclipse from windows 7 to Linux ubutinu on a Chromebook, my textures won't load

Tags: java

I am extremely new to programming java so if this is an easy fix I appreciate it.
I ported over everything including the png.

Here is my code:

```
package com.Three.ThreeD.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Texture {
    public static Render floor = 
loadBitmap("/home/chronos/Desktop/ThreeD/3d/res/textures/floor.png");
    public static Render loadBitmap(String filename) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = 
ImageIO.read(Texture.class.getResource(filename));
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            Render result = new Render(width, height);
            image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height,result.pixels, 0,width);
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("WhY dId YoU DeLeTe ThE PnG??");
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

This is what I got in the traceback :

```
WhY dId YoU DeLeTe ThE PnG??
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.Three.ThreeD.graphics.Render3D.floor(Render3D.java:58)
at com.Three.ThreeD.graphics.Screen.render(Screen.java:28)
at com.Three.ThreeD.Display.render(Display.java:137)
at com.Three.ThreeD.Display.run(Display.java:102)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at com.Three.ThreeD.graphics.Texture.loadBitmap(Texture.java:20)
at com.Three.ThreeD.graphics.Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:8)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
at com.Three.ThreeD.graphics.Texture.loadBitmap(Texture.java:11)
... 6 more
```

Comment: Did you transfer the textures too?

Comment: Care to share the stacktrace?

Comment: Aaron how do I share the traceback on this?

Comment: @Kwright02 yes I have transferred it

Comment: this directory likely needs to be changed: /home/chronos/Desktop/ThreeD/3d/res/textures/floor.png

Comment: @Kwright02 The directory is correct and I think the issue is that it can’t read the image because Linux isn’t giving it permission. I have no idea how to give it permission however.

Comment: a quick fix could be this: in command line type: chmod a+x then press space and drag the jar file in

Comment: @Kwright02 it didn’t work